# How Spring data jpa @Query annotation works

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am new to both `Spring data` and `JPA`. I am curious how the query annotation works. Like in my scenario I need all the `userIds` of an organization. So this is what i did:

```
 @Query("select o.userId from User o where o.orgId = :orgId")   
 List <Integer> findUserIdsByOrgId(@Param("orgId")int orgId);
```

The above statement works fine. I get a list of user Ids. The problem is when I alter the query to search for the `User`

```
 @Query("select o from User o where o.orgId = :orgId")  
 List <Integer> findUserIdsByOrgId(@Param("orgId")int orgId);
```

As I remove `userId` from `o.userId` the whole object is returned and not an `Integer`.

My assumption is that an error should be thrown if the return type is not matched to the one in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that [generics in Java are removed in runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

So Spring cannot make a check for generic type and trusts you that you don't mismatch type. Of course, if you return `Integer` instead of `User` (without generics) then Spring would throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Change the return type from `List<Integer>` to `List<User>` and it should work fine.

Comment: I am not saying there is any problem. its a doubt, if am getting an object by query and method return type is integer. it should throw a parsing error. how the return can change